# How to auto_increment a value from a column when inserting a new row

Tags: sql, oracle

I know that it seems similar to some questions, but I hope mine is different.

**I work with an Oracle Database**

I want to have an auto_increment on a column by using

```
 COMPUTED column and LAST_VALUE(column) + 1
```

So I have the following request :

```
ALTER TABLE schema.table (

ADD SK NUMBER ALWAYS AS (LAST_VALUE(SK)+1)

);
```

Is it gonna do the trick with only that ?

Or do I need to add a `FOR EACH ROW` sentence so that fits with my need of auto_increment ?

**EDIT According to G00dy's comment:**

The sequence :

```
create sequence SK_SEQUENCES
increment by 1
start with 1
  nomaxvalue
  minvalue 1
nocycle
order
keep;
```

The table :

```
create table schema.test(
isCurrent CHAR(10),
SK NUMBER
);
```

If I understand the comment from @g00dy,

I need to add the Sequence as a value for my column `SK`,

so I have this :

```
insert into schema.test(SK)
values (SK_SEQUENCES.nextval)
```

Then ok, it works

But when I'm adding value to the `isCurrent` column,

there's no auto_increment on the `SK` column

I guess, to have the auto_increment I need to create a trigger.

Maybe I'll have to use trigger/sequence in order to fix my issue but I don't want to..

Comment: I think you just need to create a sequence and use: `sequence_name.nexval` as value for the column you're inserting into. The sequence is just sequential number generator, which is used in insert statements to yield consecutive numbers, every time the `.nextval` is used. Within the same session you can re-use this value (after you called `.nextval` only), by using `.currval`. More information here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6015.htm#SQLRF01314. Hope this helps.

Comment: @g00dy the sequence without trigger will do the trick (auto increment when inserting new row) ? I will try, thanks for your help. I might give back my result :-)

Comment: There is no need to list all the defaults when creating a sequence. `create_sequence sk_seq` will do it.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson ok, I'll note that, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it won't work.

Firstly, the syntax is `generated always`, not just `always`, and there are no brackets around the `add` clause. However, this still won't work:

```
alter table demo
add sk integer generated always as (last_value(sk)+1);
```

fails with:

```
ORA-30484: missing window specification for this function
```

because `last_value` is an analytic function that needs to be part of a query and have a window specification like `over (partition by xxx order by yyy)`. You can't use an analytic function as a column default.

From Oracle 12.1 you can define an identity column as:

```
alter table demo
add sk integer generated always as identity;
```

In earlier Oracle versions you would need to either specify the sequence.nextval when inserting, or else create a trigger as

```
create sequence sk_seq;

create or replace trigger demo_generate_sk_trg
before insert on demo for each row
begin
    :new.dummy := sk_seq.nextval;
end;
/
```

Comment: Is there a benefit in using trigger instead of nextval in older versions?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - you use a sequence either way. A trigger saves you having to code it explicitly in multiple `insert` statements, if you have more than one.